# Calculating an angle of incidence of a ray on a curved surface

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

So I'm dealing with a ray travelling inside a hemispherical shell. The angle of entry into the shell theta2 is known, as is the inner and outer radii r1 and r2 respectively. The angle of incidence with the inner interface theta3 needs to be found. I derived something myself using the law of sines, but it doesn't match something I've found in pre-existing literature. I've triple checked my work and I'm unsure if I've done something wrong or if the expression I've found is incorrect. Help is much appreciated.

[image: Schematic and My Work]

Comment: Take the sine of both sides, $\sin(\pi - x) = \sin(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have actually gotten the right equation, just in a different form. In an earlier step, you found:

$$\frac{r_{2}}{r_{1}}\sin(\theta_{2}) =\sin(\pi -\theta_{3})$$

However, $\sin(\pi - x) = \sin(x)$ for all real $x$. (You can derive this fact using either the angle subtraction formula for $\sin$ or just by observing that the graph of $\sin(x)$ is symmetric about $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$). Thus, what you have found is equivalent to:

$$\frac{r_{2}}{r_{1}}\sin(\theta_{2}) = \sin(\theta_{3})$$